# Hiding attach button in iOS Applozic chat sdk

Tags: ios, swift, applozic

I want to hide the attach button in the chat window of the Applozic iOS Chat SDK.

I would have expected this to be included as a setting in the ALApplozicSettings class.

To do this in the Applozic Android SDK you can simply configure it by setting  *"hideAttachmentButton":true* in the applozic-settings.json. What is the equivalent in the iOS SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applozic support have sent me the following answer.

> Currently we do not have direct setting to hide attachment button. Are
>   you using our code as target dependency or bundled framework? In case
>   you are using our code as dependency, you can use below code to hide
>   the attachment button:
>
> Classname : ALChatViewController.m  Method name: viewWillAppear code
>   to add : [self.attachmentOutlet setAlpha:0.0];
>
> In case, you are using bundled framework, you can try setting up
>   framework code base.